# SQL Server : using self join to output same column with different names ends in poor performance - need improvment

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with serial numbers and by a `DeviceTypeId` it is clear from which `DeviceType` these are. The devices can be IPHone 12, Samsung XY etc. For a report I use now self joins to merge this pair of serial number and devicetypeid into a column named by the devicetype like IPhoneSerialNo. But this causes the result table to increase from the original 200000 entries to over 20 million and more  (the more joins I make). Is there a solution that does not generate so many result rows and is therefore faster? Example of my sql query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.ORDERID, t1.CUSTOMERID, t1.Serialno AS IPhoneSerialNo, 
    t2.Serialno AS SamsungSerialNo, t3.Serialno AS LGSerialNo 
FROM 
    ORDER_SERIAL_CUSTOMER t1 
LEFT JOIN  
    ORDER_SERIAL_CUSTOMER t2 ON t2.ORDERID = t1.ORDERID 
                             AND t2.DeviceTypeID = 2 
LEFT JOIN  
    ORDER_SERIAL_CUSTOMER t3 ON t3.ORDERID = t1.ORDERID 
                             AND t3.DeviceTypeID = 3 
WHERE 
    t1.DeviceTypeID = 1 AND t1.ORDERDATE > '20210309'
```

Comment: What is `ORDERID`? If it is the ID of a customer order then this seems to just get all iPhone orders and then the serial numbers of Samsung and LG phones that may or may not have been part of the same order...

Comment: What you want is a `pivot` operation. To illustrate the issue @strickt01 is talking about, have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=bd5c50841d5b2a26e58ee04ed3da4a4c). Please add an expected result to question.

Comment: The pivot operation was the solution. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Why use two additional joins? Can't the iPhoneSerialNo, SamsungSerialNo and LGSerialNo columns be the result of case expressions? e.g.:

```sql
SELECT
  ORDERID,
  CUSTOMERID,
  case when (DeviceTypeID=1) then SerialNo end as iPhoneSerialNo,
  case when (DeviceTypeID=2) then SerialNo end as SamsungSerialNo,
  case when (DeviceTypeID=3) then SerialNo end as LGSerialNo
FROM ORDER_SERIAL_CUSTOMER
WHERE ORDERDATE > '20210309';
```